# ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Array to string conversion in Laravel update method

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-6, laravel-7

I am trying to fix an update process, I have the following model that has belongs to relationship with other models and tables:

```
protected $table = 'voting_results';

protected $fillable = ['proceding_id', 'candidate_id', 'politicparty_id', 'total'];
```

From the form, I am sending the data in the following way:

```
{!! Form::model($electoralrecord, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['electoralrecords.update', $electoralrecord->id], 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="total" name="total[]" value="{{ $candidate->total }}" placeholder="Values">

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Guardar cambios"><i data-feather="save"></i> Save</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

In the controller I am receiving and trying to update the data in the table like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $data = $request->all(); 

    $ids = $request->id[0];
    $totals = $request->total[0];

    DB::table('voting_results')->where('id', $ids)
        ->update(array(['total' => $totals]));

    return redirect()->route('electoralrecords.index')
                    ->with('success','Record update!!!');

}
```

But it returns ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Array to string conversion.

Someone who can guide me, because I have tried to do the conversion to store the array data.

Making a dd of the variable $ data, this is the result:

```
array:4 [▼
  "_method" => "PATCH"
  "_token" => "dHZlKbY1x2xOteQ31pPIMkmwQc3BfHIRWrXlKU87"
  "id" => "1"
  "total" => array:27 [▼
    0 => "12"
    1 => "10"
    2 => "0"
    3 => "0"
    4 => "0"
    5 => "0"
    6 => "0"
    7 => "0"
    8 => "0"
    9 => "0"
    10 => "0"
    11 => "0"
    12 => "0"
    13 => "0"
    14 => "0"
    15 => "0"
    16 => "0"
    17 => "0"
    18 => "0"
    19 => "0"
    20 => "0"
    21 => "0"
    22 => "0"
    23 => "0"
    24 => "0"
    25 => "0"
    26 => "4"
  ]
]
```

This is a Schema and relationships

```
Schema::create('voting_results', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('proceding_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('proceding_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('proceedings')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('candidate_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('candidate_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('candidates')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('politicparty_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('politicparty_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('politicparty')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('total');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you have update() delete ‘array()’ part, since you have already defined an array using brackets ‘[]’

It might be worth changing your control code to the following:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data = $request->all(); 
    $totals = implode(',', $data['total']);

    VotingResult::where('id', $data['id'])
        ->update(array(['total' => $totals]));

    return redirect()->route('electoralrecords.index')
                    ->with('success','Record update!!!');
}
```

Also, you need to explain what columns you have and what they are for. i.e. I dont know if `total` should contain an integer or a string? should it be a total sum of totals that you have in the `$request->total`?

It would be good to also use `$cast` to indicate what some of those variables are, i.e.:

```
class VotingResult extends Model
{
   protected $cast = [
      'total' => 'json',
      'proceding_id' => 'integer',
   ];
}
```

If you have to do mathematical operations on the `total` column in the future then you might be better off changing column type of `total` to integer/double or if you need to store every single `total` value to move `total` into a separate table.

Comment: Yes, I had stayed but I already modified it, in this case it updates the first record, the rest does not update them.

Comment: I have tried doing it through foreach and different methods, but it still returns the same error.

Comment: Could you do dd($request->all()) and post results?

Comment: Also, shouldn’t you be using $data variable rather than $request for $ids and $totals?

Comment: What should ‘total’ column contain? Seems like you are trying to insert an array of data into a single column, so, you can turn totals into a string using implode - implode(‘,’, $data[‘total’]). Also, if you do want to store an array of data you might be better off storing data as a JSON

Comment: I try like this DB :: table ('voting_results') -> where ('id', $ id)
             -> update (implode (',', $ data ['total']));

Comment: But it returns Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate \ Database \ Query \ Builder :: update () must be of the type array, string given, called in C: \ laragon \ www \ electoralrecord \ app \ Http \ Controllers \ Admin \ ElectoralRecordController.php on line 257

Comment: You would have to do update([‘total’ => implode(...)])

Comment: Also, regarding $ids, just use $data[‘id’] This is because id in your request is a string

Comment: Ok, I understand but trying to do it the way you suggested, keep generating the conversion error: ErrorException (E_NOTICE) again.

Comment: DB::table('voting_results')->where('id', $id)->update(['total' => implode($data)]);

Comment: DB::table('voting_results')->where('id', $id)->update(['total' => implode(‘,’, $data[‘total’])]);   ?

Comment: Sorry, I had it badly structured.

Comment: but the result now is this:

Comment: Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (01000)
SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'total' at row 1 (SQL: update `voting_results` set `total` = 12,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4 where `id` = 1)

Comment: That means that you column in the database is too small, you need to change type and/or length of it. What type of column for total do you have?

Comment: Yes, then I was reviewing the structure of the db and this column was as an integer, then I modified it as a bigInteger and as it works it is like a string, but it inserts the entire string, by default it is registering the same record in each row and in the process is 27, so they are registering repeatedly.

Comment: So how did you want to store this data? What data in 'total' represent? Why did you have 27 items within 'total' array?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering again, the total result is from a voting process, each value in total is the value registered by each candidate in the voting process.

Comment: The table structure is proceding_id, it is where the basic data of this record and it has a relationship, then there is candidate_id which is the relationship of this with the candidates and total, is the result of each one of them.

Comment: Why want to update them? It is a process in case of an error when recording the total of each record and the values of the candidates.

Comment: Perhaps I did not detail the process well to interpret what I am really trying to do, since using the implode or foreach methods, I do not insert the values that correspond to it by the relationship that I have defined.

Comment: Sounds like the total should contain the total result, might be better to have a separate table for those values

Comment: Ok, I see I will have to do it, because the relation that there is on the table of candidates (candidate_id), is to get related results for reports.